# Avoiding use of unsafeCoerce in Hughes' list functor instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, coercion, difference-lists

I have a newtype to represent Hughes' list (ie, list construction):

```
newtype Hughes a = Hughes {unHughes :: [a] -> [a]}
```

With some functions to work on it:

```
mkHughes :: [a] -> Hughes a
mkHughes = Hughes . (++)

runHughes :: Hughes a -> [a]
runHughes h = unHughes h []
```

The `Monoid` instance is as easy as the functions above are:

```
instance Monoid (Hughes a) where
    mempty = Hughes id
    mappend (Hughes f) (Hughes g) = Hughes (f . g)
```

...but trouble arises when I get to the `Functor` and `Applicative` instances. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
instance Functor Hughes where
    fmap f (Hughes h) = Hughes $ unsafeCoerce $ fmap f . h

instance Applicative Hughes where
    pure = Hughes . (:)
    (<*>) (Hughes f) (Hughes v) = Hughes $ unsafeCoerce $
                                  (<*>) <$> f <*> unsafeCoerce v
```

The problem I have is that I don't like using `unsafeCoerce`. Is there a way to design the `Functor` instance without using it, or is it unavoidable?

Furthermore, how would I implement the `Monad` instance for this datatype?

EDIT: Unlike in the `DList` package, I want to keep the performance improvement, ie, not evaluating the `[a] -> [a]` but mapping it.

Comment: See the [`dlist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.7.1.1) package. It uses `foldr` for these instances.

Comment: @cchalmers So, it converts to standard lists, maps, and returns to difference lists. I wonder if that preserves the performance features of difference lists.

Comment: @chi My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @WillNess It seems to work just fine for me. Try it out in GHCi?

Comment: yes, it works. hmm. but it really shouldn't?

Comment: @WillNess It does *NOT* work if you `mappend` anything other than an empty list to the result of `fmap`. E.g. try ``runHughes $ (fmap fromIntegral $ mkHughes [1,2]) `mappend` mkHughes [3.0]``. With a bit more ingenuity you could crash GHC this way.

Comment: was just going to type this,  ``?_ (`unHughes` []) $ fmap (:[2]) $ Hughes (1:) `mappend` Hughes ([10,100]++)`` --> 
``[[1,2],[10,2],[100,2]]`` ; **but** 

 ``?_ (`unHughes` [[4,5,6]]) $ fmap (:[2]) $ Hughes (1:) `mappend` Hughes ([10,100]++)`` --> 
``[[1,2],[10,2],[100,2],[ *** CRASH ***``.

Comment: the real problem is,   ``(`unHughes` []) ( (f <$> Hughes (a++)) <> Hughes (b++))`` is the same as ``(`unHughes` b) (f <$> Hughes (a++))`` which is ``f <$> (a++b)`` with your Functor definition, but the types of `a` and `b` are just different so `a++b` is impossible. So it only works - with coercion - when `b == []`. IOW your Functor says `fmap` works over the whole list, when the difflist is finally run, but Monoid definition says it works only on the prefix (as does Data.DList too).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep the performance improvement", `DList` has O(1) concatenation and O(n) map. One a `DList` has been mapped it still has O(1) concatenation. Your preposed `fmap` is O(n) (and wrong). The `dlist` package has been around a while, I don't think anyone knows a faster way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is no way to implement a `Functor Hughes` instance.**

Let's examine the definition of `Hughes`:

```
data Hughes a = Hughes ([a] -> [a])
                         ^
```

We can see that the parameter `a` appears contravariant in the marked location. A `Functor` instance can only exist when all appearances of the last type parameter are covariant.

Basically you are asked to define a function `fmap :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [b]`. The problem is that you can't do anything with `[b]`, there is no function that accepts `[b]` or `b`. You can ignore it, but then the functor law `fmap id = id` will not hold.

As for DList, the `Functor` instance is valid because the implementation doesn't export the actual data constructor, only smart constructors. As a result, you cannot constuct dlist values that are arbitrary list processing functions. With provided smart constructors you can only construct dlists that are isomorphic to `[a]`, which is why the functor laws hold.

If you were to somehow hack (bring) the constructor into the scope, you would find that the functor laws don't actually hold for arbitrary functions, for example that `fmap id x /= x` if `x` is something like `DList (map negate)`.

Comment: the equivalent Data.DList.Dlist type has a Functor instance defined by `fmap f = (fromList . map f . toList)` essentially. Does this mean it is invalid in some way?

Comment: @WillNess It's only valid if `[a] -> [a]` has the right form. This is fine for `DList` because the constructor is hidden.

Comment: @WillNess It would be invalid if you could pass *arbitrary* functions to the DList constructor, which you can not.

Comment: @mniip could you give an example of a problematic function? I think that OP would have no objections to using only `singleton`, `fromList` and `empty`, as that module does. would that make defining a Functor instance possible?

Comment: @cchalmers what form is right? or is it some kind of terminology... then what does it mean please, "the right form"?

Comment: @WillNess By "right form" I meant it makes a valid `DList`, i.e. isomorphic to a list: `(fromList . toList) == id`, `(toList . fromList) == id`. If you're function was something like `map (+1)`, which isn't isomorphic to a list, you couldn't make a valid `Functor` out of it. Since the `dlist` package only lets you make valid `Dlist`s, it's safe to have that `Functor` instance.

Comment: A good reason to use a more concrete representation. The simplest one works: `data L a = Plain [a] | Pair (L a) (L a) deriving (Foldable, Traversable, Functor)`. Conversion from a list is free; conversion to a list uses the default definition.

Comment: @dfeuer That's just `Seq`, isn't it.

Comment: @mniip, no, not even close. It's (approximately) the free magma over lists. `Seq` is a length-annotated finger tree, a much richer and more flexible structure with somewhat more overhead and slower appends.

Comment: @dfeuer *"conversion to a list uses the default definition"* isn't that just  the same functional composition, under the covers, that DL does directly anyway, though? Except for the solitary `Plain [a]` case maybe -- is `deriving Foldable` smart enough to just return the list? Even then it's only a constant factor improvement over a corner case.

Comment: @WillNess, the closest data structury thing to a dlist is probably `data CNE a = Inj a | Cat (CNE a) (CNE a) ; data L a = Empty | NonEmpty (CNE a)`. The free magma over lists has the advantage of free conversion *from* lists. It may retain more space by a constant factor, but probably allocates less. I haven't done any performance testing. Either of these approaches, however, will offer a bona fide, no cheating required, `Functor` instance.

Comment: @WillNess, I'm fairly well convinced that unless there's a serious performance reason to prefer dlists, they're nice to use by hand but not worthy of library code. Once you build an API, there are nicer implementations.